# SQL - "Case when" vs condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a table `Table_A` with columns A, B and C whereby column C needs to be summed, but only if column B is a certain value. Otherwise column C may not always contain a value to be summed.

So the normal SQL of:

```
SELECT A, B, SUM(C) 
FROM Table_A 
WHERE B = 'value condition'
GROUP BY A,B
```

Works well. However, I thought I could use "CASE WHEN" to catch the conditions with zero, say, like this:

```
SELECT 
    A, B, 
    CASE WHEN B = 'value condition' THEN SUM(C) ELSE 0 END 
FROM Table_A  
GROUP BY A, B
```

I get an error, referring to the fact that it is still trying to `SUM` a value not which is not in the condition. Am I missing something? Or have I misinterpreted `CASE WHEN`?

Comment: Hint: `SUM(CASE WHEN B = 'value condition' THEN C ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: The `SUM` should be around the *entire* `CASE` expression.

Comment: Your example runs fine, you're not showing us the actual query or the actual error.  Demonstration : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=4d0d54c6cc93e2fb033848cb97bf5268

Comment: For future reference, post the complete contents (all of it - code, level, etc.) of any error message you encounter.

Answer (score 2):

You want conditional aggregation.  The `CASE` expression should appear inside `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT A, SUM(CASE WHEN B = 'value condition' THEN C ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM Table_A
GROUP BY A;
```

Note that `B` probably does not belong in the `GROUP BY` clause, given that you want to conditionally aggregate using its values.

Comment: As the OP has `B` in the `GROUP BY`, their query should run, and give the exact same results as this answer *(before the edit)*.  Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=79d6bfc09151eb936979cd34715fa95f